# Symfony login FosUserBundle redirect

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, fosuserbundle

I use this in my navbar on my web site

```
{{ render(controller('FOSUserBundle:Security:login')) }}
```

And i put the login form in my navbar where my login work when i put the correct data into.. my problem come when the data is incorrect because the render redirect me on the login.html.twig page for say me the error message. I think my problem is in this lines

```
protected function renderLogin(array $data)
   {
  return $this->render('FOSUserBundle:Security:login.html.twig', $data);
}
```

I try to change this, with the initial page or the directory of navbar but is not the good way..

How can i do??? I want the error message in the index and I do not want to redirect the login page..

Comment: Did you try to overwrite the FOSUserBundle routes?

Comment: I tried but I think I've done something wrong.. I do not know which path to edit

Answer (score 1):

if you start with FOSUserBundle you learn to import the bundle's routing files:

```
# app/config/routing.yml
fos_user:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"
```

Now take a look [here](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/routing.html) and see how you can import the different sections.

Take them over in place of the one you had first to import them all but skip the first one (security.xml)

Next open `vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml` and copy it to your own project. Change the **/login** path to your own path **/**.

**OR**

Overwrite the symfony login route:

```
# app/config/routing.yml
fos_user:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"

fos_user_security_login:
    path:      /
    defaults:  { _controller: AppBundle:Default:index }
```

add the `login_path: /` option in security.yml

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
    firewalls:
        main:
            form_login:
                login_path: /
```

Answer (score 0):

add the following to security.yml:

```
//...
    firewalls:
        main:
            // ...
            form_login:
                login_path: /
                // ...
```

- i edited my first post.